# The value along x-axis in the chart.js is breaking?

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts

I am using chart.js .The problem which I am facing is that ,the value along x-axis is breaking. And it is only the last value. I even increased the width but still same problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7diI.png)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, you can set right-padding accordingly for your chart layout.

To do so, add the following in your chart options ...

```
options: {
   layout: {
      padding: {
         right: 50, //set that suits the best
      }
   },
   ...
}
```